# Is it possible to move text up using em or %?

Tags: html, css

I have text that I don't know how to move up without using pixels - I want to maintain a responsive layout if possible. I cant use position, padding doesn't push up, and bottom only accepts pixels as well.

Does anyone have any tricks on how to get text to move up when it acts strange? I don't know if the error is in other parts of the css / html, but I've tried removing every part of the relevant css to see if I could find it, and nothing changed. I think it has to do with the inline-block and how it treats the css, but there's something I'm missing. Any guidance would be great!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J6KWj/2/

Relevant CSS:

```
#scheduleleft{
    width: 16%;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: solid rgb(58,64,70);
}

#scheduleday{
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    font-weight:500;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: rgb(29,172,214);
}

.scheduletime{
    padding: 10% 0 15% 0;
}

.scheduletime li{
    line-height: 1.25em;
}

#scheduleright{
    display: inline-block;
}

.scheduleevents{
    line-height: 1.25em;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
        <div id="schedulecontent">

        <div id="sectionheaderschedule">
                <p>Schedule</p>
        </div>

        <div id="scheduleleft">

                <div class="scheduleday">
                    <p>Monday</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scheduletime">
                <ul>
                    <li>11:00 am</li>
                    <li>2:00 pm</li>
                    <li>4:00 pm</li>
                    <li>5:00 pm</li>
                    <li>6:00 pm</li>
                    <li>7:00 pm</li>
                    <li>8:00 pm</li>
                </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="scheduleday">
                    <p>Tuesday</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scheduletime">
                <ul>
                    <li>11:00 am</li>
                    <li>2:00 pm</li>
                    <li>4:00 pm</li>
                    <li>5:00 pm</li>
                    <li>6:00 pm</li>
                    <li>7:00 pm</li>
                    <li>8:00 pm</li>
                </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="scheduleday">
                    <p>Wednesday</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scheduletime">
                <ul>
                    <li>11:00 am</li>
                    <li>2:00 pm</li>
                    <li>4:00 pm</li>
                    <li>5:00 pm</li>
                    <li>6:00 pm</li>
                    <li>7:00 pm</li>
                    <li>8:00 pm</li>
                </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="scheduleday">
                    <p>Thursday</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scheduletime">
                <ul>
                    <li>11:00 am</li>
                    <li>2:00 pm</li>
                    <li>4:00 pm</li>
                    <li>5:00 pm</li>
                    <li>6:00 pm</li>
                    <li>7:00 pm</li>
                    <li>8:00 pm</li>
                </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="scheduleday">
                    <p>Friday</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scheduletime">
                <ul>
                    <li>11:00 am</li>
                    <li>2:00 pm</li>
                    <li>4:00 pm</li>
                    <li>5:00 pm</li>
                    <li>6:00 pm</li>
                    <li>7:00 pm</li>
                    <li>8:00 pm</li>
                </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="scheduleday">
                    <p>Saturday</p>
                </div>
                <div class="scheduletime">
                <ul>
                    <li>11:00 am</li>
                    <li>2:00 pm</li>
                    <li>4:00 pm</li>
                    <li>5:00 pm</li>
                    <li>6:00 pm</li>
                    <li>7:00 pm</li>
                    <li>8:00 pm</li>
                </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="scheduleday">
                    <p>Sunday</p>
                </div>      

        </div>
```

Comment: In your fiddle which part you want to move up or which part have a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please apply `vertical-align: top;` to `#scheduleright`

```
#scheduleright{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea that class existed. It'll definitely be useful in the future.

Comment: hey sorry but have check live link given by you